# add a new columns based on the already available data

Tags: r

I have a data look's like this

df

```
    df = data.frame(
    id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
    value = c('a','b','c','d','e','a','b','c'))


    ------------
    id      value
    ------------
    1       a
    ------------
    1       b
    ------------
    1       c
    ------------
    1       d
    ------------
    1       e
    ------------
    2       a
    ------------
    2       b
    ------------
    2       c
    ------------
```

now I want to add a new column based on the value that should look like this

```
    ---------------------------
    id      value   from    to
    ---------------------------
    1       a       a       e
    ---------------------------
    1       b       a       e
    ---------------------------
    1       c       a       e
    ---------------------------
    1       d       a       e
    ---------------------------
    1       e       a       e
    ---------------------------
    2       a       a       c
    ---------------------------
    2       b       a       c
    ---------------------------
    2       c       a       c
    ---------------------------
```

I don't know if the answer is already available if it already available please provide me the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ave`, along with `head` (for first) and `tail` (for last) i.e.

```
df$from <- with(df, ave(value, id, FUN = function(i)head(i, 1)))

#and

df$to <- with(df, ave(value, id, FUN = function(i)tail(i, 1)))
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, c('from', 'to') := list(data.table::first(value), data.table::last(value)), by = id][]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(from = first(value), to = last(value)) 

id  value     from   to
1      a      a      e
1      b      a      e
1      c      a      e
1      d      a      e
1      e      a      e
2      a      a      c
2      b      a      c
2      c      a      c
```

Comment: Yeah, I was writing it as you edited your post to include the dplyr bit, I suppose

Comment: I deleted the dplyr solution from mine so you can leave yours up as well.